# Changing date with a loop vector in R

Tags: r

I'm facing a problem with a date vector where I want to change date format
I tried many things but doesn't seem to work

Lets take an example :

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
x <- c(NA, "40695", "40940", "01/03/2013", NA, "01/06/2011", NA, "40725",
      "01/07/2011", NA)
```

I tried to do it with ***replace function*** :

```
x <- replace(x, str_length(x) == 5, as.Date(x, "1899-12-30"))
x <- replace(x, str_length(x) == 10, as.Date(parse_date_time(x,"dmy")))
```

With ***for loop and ifelse*** :

```
for (i in seq_along(x)){

  ifelse(str_length(x[i]) == 5, 
         x[i] <- as.Date(x[i], "1899-12-30"),
         ifelse(str_length(x[i]) == 10,
                x[i] <- as.Date(parse_date_time(x[i],"dmy"))), "pas de donnees")

}
```

With ***base R*** :

```
x[str_length(x) == 5] <- as.Date(x, "1899-12-30")
```

I get the following error

> Error in x[str_length(x) == 5] <- as.Date(x, "1899-12-30") :    NAs
>   are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to have dates when i can and if NA it could returning me NA

Comment: What would be the date for `40940`?

Comment: it would be 2011-06-01 (as.Date(40695, "1899-12-30")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `which` to drop NAs when indexing. Also, prepare an empty vector with Date-NAs, since replacing the original values does not work (you are trying to replace character with Date in a vector).

This works (base)

```
# empty vector with Date-class NA
z <- rep(as.Date(NA), length(x))

z[which(nchar(x) == 5)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(x[which(nchar(x) == 5)]), 
                                    origin="1899-12-30")

z[which(nchar(x) == 10)] <- as.Date(x[which(nchar(x) == 10)], 
                                    format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you very nice, why my ifelse satement doesnt work ?